# while loop not breaking with same condition as i

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to get my code to spit back a response at the user when the while condition is true from an if statement with the same condition, the problem is, even when the user types "Yes"/"No", it spits out the if statement, but it doesn't break the loop, here is my code, any thoughts?

```
print("Do you kill it for the stick? (Yes/No/Help)")
userInput = input()

while userInput != "Yes" or "No":
    Help = "Do you kill the ant or not? Yes/No"
    if userInput == "Yes":
        print("Wow, you're a monster, ok then")
    elif userInput == "No":
        print("Woos...")
    elif userInput == "Help":
        print(Help)
    else:
        print("You've gotta choose!")
    userInput = input()
    Help = ""
```

Comment: Try `while userInput not in ("Yes", "No")`

Comment: Did you now that the input method accept a string as parameter? So you can have userInput = input("Do you kill the ant or not? Yes/No").

Comment: You are resetting the value of userInput as `userInput = input()` later on in the while loop, so userInput will never retain its value and hence will never break from the loop.